# Read names line by line and perform a certain function on it in Bash scripting

Tags: bash

I'm writing  a bash script, creating users.
I want to read a text file with names line by line and perform a function on each.
I've tried Googling a lot, but nothing is working out for me.
I want user to enter the path of file with the names in it one on each line and then I'll add function on it.

```
echo "Enter file path:"
read line
while read line
do
  name=$line
  echo "Text read from file - $name"
done < $1
```

How can I do this?
I'd appreciate a little help on that,
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few subtleties that will help your script. You should set `IFS` (internal field separator) to only break on `newline` before you read the filename. This will insure you get the full filename if it contains whitespace and is unquoted. Restore `IFS` after the filename read. You will also want to check whether `$line` has been read following the `read` to insure you get the last line in the event there is no `newline` at the end of the last line in the data file.

Additionally, whenever you read a filename from a user, you should validate that it is a valid filename before attempting to read from it:

```
#!/bin/bash

oifs=$IFS                               # save internal field separator
IFS=$'\n'                               # set IFS to newline (if whitespace in path/name)

echo -n "Enter file path/name: "        # suppress newline
read fname                              # read full-path/filename

IFS=$oifs                               # restore default IFS=$' \t\n'

[ -r "$fname" ] || {                    # validate input file is readable
    printf "error: invalid filename '%s'\n" "$fname"
    exit 1
}

while read line || [ -n "$line" ]       # protect against no newline for last line
do
    name=$line
    echo "Text read from file - $name"
done < "$fname"                         # double-quote fname

exit 0
```

**Sample use/output:**

```
$ bash readfn.sh
Enter file path/name: dat/ecread.dat
Text read from file - read: 4163419415       0      0     4163419415   0   4395.007      0
Text read from file - read: 4163419415       0      0     4163419415   0   4395.007      0
Text read from file - read: 4163419415       0      0     4163419415   0   4395.007      1
Text read from file - read: 4163419415       0      0     4163419415   0   4395.007      0
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answers, however I'm just confused at one point.
Why you're using  -r  here:

[ -r "$fname" ] || {                    # validate input file is readable
    printf "error: invalid filename '%s'\n" "$fname"
    exit 1
}

Comment: You can use `-e` (does it exist), `-f` (is it a file), etc., but the most specific is `-r` (is it readable [which encompasses existence, being a file, and having sufficient permission to read]). Or you can take your chances and not test at all (not recommended). The point being, that any user input should be considered **suspect** until verified. No telling what will be entered.

Comment: Thank you so much.. `||`  this means OR, right?  Sorry for such noob questions, but I've just started..

Comment: Yes, it is just a shorthand for `if [! -r "$fname" ]; then`. You can use `command1 && command2` or `command1 || command2` in many situations. This use is called a **compound command**. If multiple statements follow, then wrap all the related statements in `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo "Enter file path:"
read filepath
while read line
do
  name="$line"
  echo "Text read from file - $name"
done < "$filepath"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will sort you out, give it a go.

```
echo "Enter file path:"
read filename    
while read line    
do    
  name=$line  
  echo "Text read from file - $name"    
done < $filename
```

Comment: yeah I know, I hadn't finished my answer and you posted yours. 
In Umair's original bash script, you were assigning the file name to the line variable, but then the while loop was reading from $1 (which most likely was not set). The while loop then would have overridden the line variable.